# lockCanvas failing when screen orientation changes

Tags: java, android, surfaceholder

I'm trying to build a live wallpaper in Android, but it crashes the app when the orientation changes. It looks like it's crashing when trying to lockCanvas on the surface holder, but I'm not sure what I can do to prevent it.

Here's the class:

```
public class LiveWallpaperService extends WallpaperService
{
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MyWallpaperEngine();
    }

    class MyWallpaperEngine extends Engine
    {
        private final Handler handler = new Handler();
        private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                draw();
            }
        };
        private boolean visible = true;

        Paint paint;

        MyWallpaperEngine() {
            paint = new Paint();
        }

        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            this.visible = visible;

            if (visible) {
                handler.post(drawRunner);
            }
            else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            this.visible = false;
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        }

        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
            draw();
        }

        void draw() {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

            Canvas c = null;

            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();

                if (c != null) {
                    // Paint stuff here.
                }
            }
            finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }

            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
            if (visible) {
                handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the exception that happens when the orientation changes:

```
E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
E/Surface: dequeueBuffer failed (No such device)
E/BaseSurfaceHolder: Exception locking surface
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
           at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
           at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:318)
           at com.android.internal.view.BaseSurfaceHolder.internalLockCanvas(BaseSurfaceHolder.java:194)
           at com.android.internal.view.BaseSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(BaseSurfaceHolder.java:158)
           at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine$1.lockCanvas(WallpaperService.java:262)
           at greencell.bitpatternswallpaper.LiveWallpaperService$MyWallpaperEngine.draw(LiveWallpaperService.java:206)
           at greencell.bitpatternswallpaper.LiveWallpaperService$MyWallpaperEngine$1.run(LiveWallpaperService.java:51)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Update:

I've checked many other threads that seem to have the same issue but the only thing that I can do so far is to wrap `unlockCanvasAndPost` and `lockCanvas` in a try catch to ignore `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707707/app-crashing-after-theme-update?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I don't follow. The question in that link is completely different to what's happening here.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with the code you provided, but I couldn't. Does it happen for any specific Android version/device?

Comment: Right now I'm testing on a Pixel 2 with android version 8.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `draw()`, I'd try moving `handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);` just before the `try` block. It could be that `onOffsetsChanged()` is getting called on orientation change, and that the previous thread on the handler might not have called `unlockCanvasAndPost(c)` yet, which explains why you're getting an error with `lockCanvas()` at that point. However, this shouldn't be the case if the code you've posted here exactly matches what you're running locally, since you haven't overriden `onOffsetsChanged()`.

Another thing you could try is overriding `onSurfaceChanged()` and clearing the handler queue like this:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
    super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
}
```

Ultimately, all of the examples regarding `WallpaperService` that I've read online have a `try`-`finally` block with the lock/unlock canvas logic, so I wouldn't be worried.

Comment: The error still triggers once in a while but it does feel more stable. Yes I noticed all the examples ended up with a try catch, just feels dirty, but I guess I'll need to live with it :). Thank you!

Comment: It is pretty weird, but I'm glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

try `android:configChanges="orientation"` on your
`<service android:name=".LiveWallpaperService" />` in Manifest

example: 
`<service android:name=".LiveWallpaperService"
android:configChanges="orientation" />`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though didn't notice any difference.